# Dieudonne's proof that precompact and complete implies compact

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, compactness, complete-spaces

> Let $(E, d)$ be a metric space. Then $E$ is **precompact** if and only
> if $$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists F\subset
>  E\wedge|F|\in\mathbb{N})(\forall x\in E)(d(x,F)<\varepsilon).$$

Dieudonne's proof goes as follows:

> Suppose we have an open covering $(U_\lambda)_{\lambda\in L}$ of $E$
> such that no finite subfamily is a covering of $E$. We define by
> induction a sequence $(B_n)$ of balls in the following way: from
> assumption, it follows that the diameter of $E$ is finite, and by
> multiplying the distance on $E$ by a constant, we may assume that
> $\delta(E)<1/2$, hence $E$ is a ball $B_0$ of radius $1$...

I don't understand how $B_0$ is being defined here. Precompactness implies that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a finite family $(y_j)_{1\leq j\leq m}$ of elements of $E$ such that
$$(\forall x)\left(x\in E\Rightarrow\inf_{1\leq j\leq m}d(x,y_j)<\varepsilon\right).$$
Why does this imply that $\delta(E)<1/2$ and how does this show that $E=B_0$ where $B_0$ is a ball with radius 1? What is the center of $B_0$? (how can you say something is a ball without specifying a radius *and* a center?)

Can someone please help define $B_0$ explicity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does *not* imply that $\delta(E)<\frac12$. But precompactness implies that $\delta(E)<\infty$. And the Dieudonné multiplies the original distance $d$ defined on $E$ by a constant $K>0$, thereby getting a new distance $d_K$. And $K$ is chosen so that the diameter of $E$ is smaller than $\frac12$. Then $B_0$ is *any* ball with radius $1$ (with respect to $d_K$).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is it ok if I ask you a few more questions? I am still not fully sure I understand this. (1) Are we allowed to just use $d_K$ instead of the original $d$? Does that mean the entire recursion uses $d_K$? (2) How can I show that a ball with radius 1 w.r.t $d_K$ which equals to $E$ exists?

Comment: (1) Yes, because $(E,d)$ is compact if and only if $(E,d_K)$ is compact, $(E,d)$ is precompact if and only if $(E,d_K)$ is precompact, and $(E,d)$ is complete if and only if $(E,d_K)$ is complete. And, yes, the whole recursion is done on $(E,d_K)$. (2) You take any element $x$ of $E$ and you consider the open ball with center $x$ and radius $1$ (with respect to $d_K$).